# Find $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}{\mathrm{e}^{-x}\int_{0}^{x}{f\left(y\right)\mathrm{e}^{y}\,\mathrm{d}y}}$

Tags: integration, limits

Given $f(x)$ is a continuous function defined in $(0,\: \infty)$ such that $$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=1$$ Then Find $$L=\lim_{x \to \infty}{\mathrm{e}^{-x}\int_{0}^{x}{f\left(y\right)\mathrm{e}^{y}\,\mathrm{d}y}}$$

My try:

we have $$L=\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{\int_{0}^{x}{f\left(y\right)\mathrm{e}^{y}\,\mathrm{d}y}}{e^x}}$$

If the numerator is finite then $L=0$ else by L'Hopital's Rule we have $\infty/\infty$ form we get

$$L=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f\left(x\right)\mathrm{e}^{x}}{\mathrm{e}^x}=\lim_{x \to \infty}{f\left(x\right)}=1$$

But how to tell whether $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\int_{0}^{x}{f\left(y\right)\mathrm{e}^{y}\,\mathrm{d}y}$ is Finite or Infinite?

Comment: Do not use $x$ for the limits of  integration as well as the variable of integration. Write $\int_0^{x} e^{t} f(t) dt$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$, we have $f(x)>1/2$ for all $x>N$, where $N$ is sufficiently large. Ignoring the integral over $[0,N]$ (which is a fixed finite value), we consider the remaining part:
$$\int_N^\infty f(x)e^xdx\geq\frac{1}{2}\int_N^\infty e^xdx$$

Comment: can i know why equality also came from the strict inequality?

Comment: @Umeshshankar Because $\int_N^{+\infty}$ is the same as $\lim_{s\to+\infty}\int_N^s$, and one should recall from calculus that taking the limit does not necessarily preserve strict inequality, e.g. $\frac{1}{n^2}<\frac{1}{n}$, but the limit of both sides are $0$ when $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $ \varepsilon>0 $, since $ \lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}{f\left(x\right)}=1 $, there exists some $ x_{0}>0 $ such that $ \left(\forall x\geq x_{0}\right),\ \left|f\left(x\right)-1\right|<\varepsilon \cdot $

Let $ x\geq x_{0} $, we have : \begin{aligned}\left|\mathrm{e}^{-x}\int_{0}^{x}{\mathrm{e}^{y}\left(f\left(y\right)-1\right)\mathrm{d}y}\right|&=\left|\mathrm{e}^{-x}\int_{0}^{x_{0}}{\mathrm{e}^{y}\left(f\left(y\right)-1\right)\mathrm{d}y}+\mathrm{e}^{-x}\int_{x_{0}}^{x}{\mathrm{e}^{y}\left(f\left(y\right)-1\right)\mathrm{d}y}\right|\\ &\leq\mathrm{e}^{-x}\int_{0}^{x_{0}}{\mathrm{e}^{y}\left|f\left(y\right)-1\right|\mathrm{d}y}+\mathrm{e}^{-x}\int_{x_{0}}^{x}{\mathrm{e}^{y}\left|f\left(y\right)-1\right|\mathrm{d}y}\\ &\leq\mathrm{e}^{-x}\int_{0}^{x_{0}}{\mathrm{e}^{y}\left|f\left(y\right)-1\right|\mathrm{d}y}+\varepsilon\,\mathrm{e}^{-x}\int_{x_{0}}^{x}{\mathrm{e}^{y}\,\mathrm{d}y}\end{aligned}

$ \mathrm{e}^{-x}\int_{0}^{x_{0}}{\mathrm{e}^{y}\left(f\left(y\right)-1\right)\mathrm{d}y}\underset{x\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 $, thus, there exists some $ x_{1}>0 $ such that $ \mathrm{e}^{-x}\int_{0}^{x_{0}}{\mathrm{e}^{y}\left|f\left(y\right)-1\right|\mathrm{d}y}<\varepsilon $, hence, if $ x\geq \max{\left(x_{0},x_{1}\right)} $, we have : \begin{aligned}\left|\mathrm{e}^{-x}\int_{0}^{x}{\mathrm{e}^{y}\left(f\left(y\right)-1\right)\mathrm{d}y}\right|\leq \varepsilon+\varepsilon\,\mathrm{e}^{-x}\int_{x_{0}}^{x}{\mathrm{e}^{y}\,\mathrm{d}y}\leq\varepsilon+\varepsilon\,\mathrm{e}^{-x}\int_{-\infty}^{x}{\mathrm{e}^{y}\,\mathrm{d}y}=2\varepsilon\end{aligned}

Thus $$ \lim_{x\to +\infty}{\mathrm{e}^{-x}\int_{0}^{x}{\mathrm{e}^{y}\left(f\left(y\right)-1\right)\mathrm{d}y}}=0 $$

And we have : \begin{aligned} \mathrm{e}^{-x}\int_{0}^{x}{\mathrm{e}^{y}f\left(y\right)\mathrm{d}y}&=\mathrm{e}^{-x}\int_{0}^{x}{\mathrm{e}^{y}\,\mathrm{d}y}+\mathrm{e}^{-x}\int_{0}^{x}{\mathrm{e}^{y}\left(f\left(y\right)-1\right)\mathrm{d}y}\\&=1-\mathrm{e}^{-x}+\mathrm{e}^{-x}\int_{0}^{x}{\mathrm{e}^{y}\left(f\left(y\right)-1\right)\mathrm{d}y}\underset{x\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}1\end{aligned}

Comment: wow what a nice analysis, kudos to your solution i am so happy to learn solving a problem in this way

Answer (score 1):

As long as the denominator tends to $\infty$ we can always apply L'Hopital's Rule. So the answer is $1$. (You need not bother about the numerator being bounded; it will never be).

Comment: This is correct (and mentioned in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Hôpital%27s_rule) but apparently unknown to many.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for the comment. I got multiple down votes for this.

Comment: I must have mentioned this (in)finitely many times here about the usage of L'Hospital's in my answers and comments here. But perhaps I need to try harder to make this as popular as "L'Hospital's works on $0/0$".

Comment: +1 already there to compensate the undeserved downvote.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you. I have seen you promoting L'Hopitals rule without $\frac 0 0$ or $\frac {\infty} { \infty}$ form earlier and I think we should keep on promoting the use of this rule.